# Error at Click evant: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, indexing, click, label

I have this function that will create a `Click event` for all the labels that are in the `label list`. `label list` is a list of labels:

```
Label[] label = new Label[50]; // 50 is only a ramdom number, is not the real number of number of labels
```

`ii` is the `number of labels` from `label`.

`orar[k]` is a list that contains some fields:

```
static List<Orar> orar = new List<Orar>();
```

`Orar` is a class for the list. The list have the same number of fields as `ii` (number of labels).

This is the code for creating the `Click` event.

```
for (int k = 0; k < ii; k++)
            {
                label[k].Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    string materie = "", profesor = "", detali = "", zi = "", formatmaterie = "", sala = "", inputbox = "", inceputora = "", formatOra = "", saptamana = "", AMPM1 = "", p1 = "";
                    int cand = 1, vl1 = 0, apm = 0;

                    materie = orar[k].materie;
                    profesor = orar[k].profesor;
                    detali = orar[k].detali;
                    zi = orar[k].zi;
                    formatmaterie = orar[k].formatmaterie;
                    sala = orar[k].sala;
                    inceputora = orar[k].inceputora;
                    formatOra = orar[k].formatora.ToString();
                    saptamana = orar[k].saptamana;
                    AMPM1 = orar[k].apm;

                    vl1 = vl11;
                    cand = 1;

                    p1 = "Detali materie !";
                    apm = 0;

                    inputbox = Programarii.InputAddOrar.Show(p1, ref materie, ref formatOra, ref sala, ref inceputora, ref formatmaterie, ref profesor, ref zi, ref detali, ref saptamana, ref vl1, ref cand, ref apm, ref AMPM1).ToString();
                };
            }
```

The problem is that don't work. I have this error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have to allocate memory to the orar elements in List.

So:

```
orar.Add( new Orar());
```

Then do your stuff:

```
orar[i].someProperty = "SetProperty";
```

**EDIT:**
Captured variables could be the cause here. Try something for me and do this instead:

```
for (int k = 0; k < ii; k++)
            {
                int j = k ; //replace the k's in the lambdas with j  
                label[k].Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    string materie = "", profesor = "", detali = "", zi = "", formatmaterie = "", sala = "", inputbox = "", inceputora = "", formatOra = "", saptamana = "", AMPM1 = "", p1 = "";
                    int cand = 1, vl1 = 0, apm = 0;

                    materie = orar[j].materie;
                    profesor = orar[j].profesor;
                    detali = orar[j].detali;
                    zi = orar[j].zi;  
                    formatmaterie = orar[j].formatmaterie;
                    sala = orar[j].sala;
                    inceputora = orar[j].inceputora;
                    formatOra = orar[j].formatora.ToString();
                    saptamana = orar[j].saptamana;
                    AMPM1 = orar[j].apm;

                    vl1 = vl11;
                    cand = 1;

                    p1 = "Detali materie !";
                    apm = 0;

                    inputbox = Programarii.InputAddOrar.Show(p1, ref materie, ref formatOra, ref sala, ref inceputora, ref formatmaterie, ref profesor, ref zi, ref detali, ref saptamana, ref vl1, ref cand, ref apm, ref AMPM1).ToString();
                };
            }
```

Comment: This is not the problem becouse first I creat the labels after the list.

Comment: And you are definitely allocating objects to the Label array and List?

Comment: @AnDr3yy I'm not sure.. maybe it is captured variables at hand? 
Try my suggestion and create a local variable, replace the k's with that local variable as shown in my example ^^. And also does the exception occur when you click a Label or before?

Answer (score 0):

if `ii = 50` then change `k < ii - 1`

Comment: If ii is 50, k < ii will loop 49 times. ii-1 will make it loop 48 times.

Comment: Yes, but is a problem. For all the labels, the click event will display the last element of the list, not his element.